# Shared access signatures for a large number of azure blob uri in a static html to be embedded in an iframe

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have static html that will be embedded in an iframe. The markup contains lots of link to different content types like images, pdfs, js, css etc. These will all be placed in an azure blob in a container. This is an e-learning static html so it may contain hundreds of resources. To access it, each link will have to be concatenated with a shared access signature (SAS) so it can be downloaded in a browser, when that iframe is loaded.

My problem is do I have to go over each link (hundreds of links) and concatenate the SAS so that when the static html is embedded in an iframe, the browser will be able to download each resource in azure blob?

Here is a sample link in the inspector
[image]

Or is there a simple way like a token (oauth or something) to be used by the browser and without going over each link to add SAS, would use that token for the browser to be granted permission to download the resource?

Comment: How's going? Has your issue been solved?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure storage also supports using Azure AD to authorize access, details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad

And this is a detailed guide about using the access token to access Azure storage blobs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet

Simple Demo:

```html
<html>

    <body>
    
        <div onclick="downloadFromURL(this)">https://stantest1016.blob.core.windows.net/static/1.png </div>
                
    
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
        var access_token="<access token>";
        function downloadFromURL(object){
            var requestURL = $(object).html();
            $.ajax({
                url: requestURL,
                type: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ access_token,
                    'x-ms-version': '2017-11-09'
                },
                responseType: 'blob',
                success: function (result) {
                      var blob = new Blob([result]);
                      var link=document.createElement('a');
                      link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                      link.download="1.png";
                      link.click();
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
            
        }
    
    </script>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

And if all blobs are stored in one container or storage account, maybe you can generate a SAS token with whole container or storage account read permission so that users could use this SAS token to access all blobs directly instead of one blob one SAS token.

Comment: may i know how this token based authentication works? Let's say a user clicks on a hyperlink on a page, that hyperlink points to a resource in an azure blob storage. How will the browser use the token to download the resource when there is no SAS?

Comment: If you want to download some resources by access token, I think you need an external function to pass Azure AD Auth. I have updated my answer with a simple html js demo.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i need if i want to use ajax to request for a blob. But for a static html site that will be embedded in an iframe, and contains thousands of a tag links that is statically generated (eg: <a href="https://somestorage.blobl.core.windows.net/someresource/AwWFEFsfaeksiuhfwe.png"></a>), I will have to manually append a SAS to each hyperlink. This static site with its hyperlinks is generated by a third party e-learning authoring tool. Is this the only way and do I have to do it one by one to each link so when user clicks it, the url has the SAS appended on it?

Comment: If the iframe under the same domain of your main page, you can use jquey contents() function to access and do some actions by js. But if they are not under the same domain, I think the only way is to append SAS tokens manually.

Comment: Btw, this is the reference of  jquey contents() function: https://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: Your demo looks good for ajax requests.. But for <a> link elements with hundreds of urls,..manual append of SAS tokens should be the approach?

Comment: Hi @Alexander Yes, append SAS tokens should be the approach, you can use user delegation SAS to generate SAS token and append to your blob urls. Details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas